# Wordpress only displays header and footer in IE8

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, wordpress-thesis-theme

That basically sums it up. The blog renders fine in FF and Safari and an IE9 and 10, but anything before that (IE8, IE7, etc.) shows only the header and footer. I'm using the latest version of WordPress as well as the Thesis theme, although I have heavily customized it. I checked my markup validation and all that. I just can't figure this one out. Thanks in advance.

Here's the site: http://www.massageschoolsguide.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE is rendering that way because of the DOCTYPE, is my guess.

[Discussion about how IE determines which rendering engine to use](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/02/how-ie8-determines-document-mode.aspx)

If you open IE developer tools and switch the document mode from IE7 to IE8, it looks fine. Unless you have to target <=IE7 for your client, change out the doctype in your Thesis template.

Other then that, the height:7px in custom.css seems to also be the culprit.